# Spring Controller +Jackson + Joda Date Time: How maintain Timezone?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, timezone, jackson, jodatime

### My Configuration

Spring 3.2.5.Release

Jackson 2.3.0:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Joda Time 2.3:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**I used this global Spring MVC global settings:**

```
<!--Jackson - objectMapper format date setting -->
<beans:bean id="objectMapper"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
    p:indentOutput="true" p:simpleDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ">
</beans:bean>

<!--Jackson - registerModule JodaModule -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    p:targetObject-ref="objectMapper" p:targetMethod="registerModule">
    <beans:property name="arguments">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Spring MVC:  setting objectMapper in converter MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter-->
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <beans:property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

### My Problem:

**Jackson (I suppose..) overwrite the timezone +8:00 with Z.**

In fact, if i send a JSON request with a date with **+8:00** timezone:

```
{
    "date": "2014-01-28T23:00:00.000+08:00"
}
```

....the request is handle by a classic spring MVC @Controller:

```
public JsonResponse insert(@RequestBody BeanDto beanWithDate)
```

BeanDto has "DateTime date", property.

The property date of BeanDto has this value:

```
date = 2014-01-28T23:00:00.000Z
```

### My question:

**How to maintain the json request's Timezone?**

Another little question:
Is there a more smart solution for manage dateTime format in spring mvc configuration file?

Thank you,
Alessandro