# How to set timezone of jackson on a per-request-basis?

Tags: java, json, datetime, timezone, jackson

I am using Spring WebMVC, JodaTime and Jackson to build a RESTful webservice.
Every user who performs actions on this webservice has his default timezone saved in the database.
I need to provide all timestamp in the users timezone. I am able to convert every timestamp in a response object to the correspondending timezone of the user, but jackson deserializes every timestamp to a specific timezone, for example UTC.

How do I prevent jackson from doing this? I want a datetime field to be serialized in its timezone, not the timezone set for jackson.
I am using full ISO6801 format.

**Edit:**

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, there is currently a discussion going on at Github about this topic:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/issues/43

Comment: Some code and data examples would be helpful.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possibly related: [How to serialize Joda DateTime with Jackson JSON processer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3269459/634824)

Comment: @MattJohnson I appreciate your links but I don't see how a code example would be any helpful here, mainly because I use Spring and I therefore don't invoke the ObjectMapper instance myself. Also the other question is only somehow related because I don't have any problems with serializing in general.

Comment: However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440619/spring-controller-jackson-joda-date-time-how-maintain-timezone?rq=1) question is related but unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider customizing the standard Joda time deserializer to read the timezone information from a thread local variable set by every request.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonTimezone {

    public static class DataTimeDeserializerTimeZone extends DateTimeDeserializer {
        public static final ThreadLocal<DateTimeZone> TIME_ZONE_THREAD_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<DateTimeZone>() {
            @Override
            protected DateTimeZone initialValue() {
                return DateTimeZone.getDefault();
            }
        };

        public DataTimeDeserializerTimeZone() {
            super(DateTime.class);
        }

        @Override
        public ReadableDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            return super.deserialize(jp, ctxt).toDateTime().withZone(TIME_ZONE_THREAD_LOCAL.get());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JodaModule module = new JodaModule();
        module.addDeserializer(DateTime.class,
                (JsonDeserializer) new DataTimeDeserializerTimeZone());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.parse("2014-02-03T10:00");
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(dateTime1);
        System.out.println(json + " " + TIME_ZONE_THREAD_LOCAL.get());
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, DateTime.class));
        TIME_ZONE_THREAD_LOCAL.set(DateTimeZone.forID("US/Hawaii"));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, DateTime.class));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1391418000000 Europe/Oslo
2014-02-03T10:00:00.000+01:00
2014-02-02T23:00:00.000-10:00
```

The value of the `TIME_ZONE_THREAD_LOCAL` static variable should be set to the correct timezone before JSON data reaches Jackson.

Comment: If extending the existing serializer is the only option, I will go for that. Thanks for the example!